# Was mortality higher on French slave ships and if so, why?

Tags: slavery, ships, atlantic-slave-trade

I was recently at the African American museum; part of the large history exhibit included a wall of slave-bearing ships with the name, dates, and flag under which the ship sailed. I noticed a pattern: most of the ships killed between 1/4 and 1/3 of the slaves; however, the French ships tended to have a much higher death rate (if I remember correctly, the average was between 1/3 and 1/2). Was this an actual trend, and if so, was there any particular reason for it?

Comment: I think that the question oversimplifies the data. There are many factors to consider when trying to determine reasons for death rates on slave ships (age, gender, port of origin & flag carrier, destination and - most importantly - date). Can you perhaps at least give an idea of the time period (e.g. pre-1700, 1700-1750 etc) for your data?

Comment: Can you provide more detail on your data? I assume the museum you refer to was [the Smithsonian National Museum of African American History & Culture](https://nmaahc.si.edu/)?  As Lars Bosteen points out in his answer, information recorded,  [here](http://www.slavevoyages.org/estimates/hOYKkFTn) for instance,  does not seem to correspond with your  figures.

Answer (score 15):

[French slave trading practices](http://etymonline.com/columns/frenchslavery.htm) were more abusive than comparable American practices for several reasons.

1. The French sent out more and larger ships than the Anglo Americans. Conditions were much worse with overcrowding, etc. than on smaller ships.
2. The destination for French slaves were Caribbean sugar islands, which were more nearly comparable to similar Spanish colonies, rather than more temperate climates such as Virginia. Because French slaves died off at a much greater rate than those of American destinations in any event, the French "shippers" were less concerned about delivering slaves in "good" condition. From the link:

> Conditions on sugar plantations were harsh (though French sugar colonies were no better or worse than Spanish, Dutch, or British ones). During the eight-month sugar harvest, slaves sometimes worked continuously almost around the clock. Accidents caused by long hours and primitive machinery were horrible. In the big plantations, the captives lived in barracks; women were few and families nonexistent.
>
> Compared to this, North American cotton plantation slavery featured much less ferocious labor and allowed family units to exist. Which is one reason France required a steady flow of thousands of slaves a year -- to replace the ones the French had worked to death -- while America's slave population grew naturally even after the U.S. slave trade had ended.

3. The movement for "Abolition" started earlier in France, 18th century vs. 19th century, which is to say that opinion became more polarized, sooner, in France than in America.

Comment: Nice answer, but I do not understand the second point. I mean, regardless of the expected profit they expected out of each slave, each dead slave meant a net loss. Maybe you could explain it a little more?

Comment: @SJuan76: Slavery was "barely" profitable in Virginia, meaning that planters would only buy slaves in "good" condition. Bad condition, no sale. In the Caribbean, the "half live" of a slave was 8 years. If bad condition meant that the slave could work only four, the shipper could recoup 50% of the normal sale price. I modified point 2 in line with this comment.

Comment: In 3. are you saying that the activities of the French abolitionist movement made French slavery more brutal?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: No, I said that it made things more "polarized." That is, when the abolitionists start demanding an end to slavery, the pro slavery people get more defensive and "harder" in their ways, if only to "justify" their position

Comment: I "noticed" that you "tend" to use "quotes" pretty "often" in this "answer."

Comment: @kirkpatt 3 times, justifiably. He says "shippers" and "good" because he's talking about people, and that's a pretty messed up way to describe transporting people against their will, and he gets the point across without putting himself in the position of actually being the person to talk about them this way. I assume he uses "abolition" because it might have been a different name in France (the word is the same in French) and it isn't the same abolition movement we refer to in the U.S.

Comment: @JackArbiter I was referring more to the comments he made on the answer. I didn't mean they were incorrect or anything, just noticing there were a lot of them.

Comment: #2 is not good analysis. Can you explain why a person from Nigeria would be more likely to die on Martinique with a nearly identical climate? Virginia (or worse still, New York) has a hard winter which was completely foreign to equatorial Africans. North America introduced more _climatic_ stress than the Carribean. The matter at hand was the work the the slaves were put to, with sugar growing being notoriously brutal compared to tobacco and later cotton in the 13 Colonies. #3 also needs some sort of connection between 'polarization' and fatality rate, which I don't see.

Comment: @kingledion: It's was not the "climate" per se, but the crops that were grown. Sugar is grown most of the year, and therefore the slaves were worked until they dropped. Northern crops like cotton have "busy" seaons and "slack" seasons, and were therefore less profitable, but slaves there were given breaks. I spelled out the key portions of the link. Polarization tends to inflame the people that do own slaves to treat them worse. U.S. slavery was more brutal in 1850 than 1750.

Comment: @TomAu I'm not sure I entirely understand your part 2. While the slavers may have been more willing to let slaves become ill on the ships, it seems clear that there would be no reason to let them die more. Dead slaves, after all, can't sell either. Of course, increased illness can lead to increased death, but that seems like something the slavers would have taken into account. It seems as if you are talking about mortality rates after selling, where I think my question (or rather, the statistics on the wall) were pre-selling.

Comment: @anon: French sugar planters on Martinique made higher profits than Virginia cotton planters so they paid more per slave. In that instance, the French shippers could afford to "take their chances" with slaves dying. The Virginians paid less so the shippers had to make sure that as many slaves as possible survived to cover their fixed costs. So through the cost and pricing structure, mortality rates at the end location affected mortality rates on ships.

Comment: Your link doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 14):

**SHORT ANSWER**

**Basically, NO.**

The two main databases on the trans-Atlantic slave trade do **not** support the idea that French slave ships had, on average, higher mortality rates than American carriers. **In fact, data suggests that the opposite is probably true.** This was most likely due to American slavers being less experienced at handling slave ships than the British and the French.

**The main trend on mortality shows a decline over time for most flag carriers.** The generally higher mortality rates for the early period of the trans-Atlantic slave trade can be attributed to slow ships (=more time at sea), worse conditions, and inexperienced crews.

---

**DETAILED ANSWER**

Shocking though the Atlantic slave trade was, the mortality statistics cited in the question may not tally with other sources.  The data quoted here comes mostly from the Du Bois Institute dataset (in ‘Transoceanic Mortality: The Slave Trade in Comparative Perspective’ by Herbert S. Klein, Stanley L. Engerman, Robin Haines, and Ralph Shlomowitz) and [the Voyages Database (from ‘The Trans-Atlantic Slave Trade: A Database’ published by Cambridge University Press).](http://www.slavevoyages.org) These two sources seem to be the two most comprehensive sets yet compiled.

The total number of slaves shipped to the Americas is variously estimated to be [12 million](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic_slave_trade#Atlantic_shipment), [12.5 million](http://www.slavevoyages.org/assessment/estimates), and 13.9 million (Edward Dunber, cited in P. Curtin).

The [**three largest flag carriers** between 1501 and 1870](http://www.slavevoyages.org/assessment/estimates) were the **Portuguese (around 5.8 million** embarked), the **British (around 3.2 million** embarked), and the **French (around 1.4 million** embarked).

Estimates of **mortality rates during shipment vary from [12.5%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic_slave_trade#Atlantic_shipment) to around 16%.** Mortality rates decreased over time from around [21% during the period 1601-1650](http://www.slavevoyages.org/assessment/estimates) to about [6% for the period 1751-1800](http://www.slavevoyages.org/assessment/estimates) (during which time the trade peaked), and then increased during the period [1801 – 1850 to about 13%](http://www.slavevoyages.org/assessment/estimates). The decline was partly due to improved conditions (though probably for economic rather than humanitarian reasons) and faster ships, meaning less time at sea. The increase at the tail end of the slave trade was mostly due to the [Portuguese who accounted for over 75% of the trade](http://www.slavevoyages.org/assessment/estimates) in this period as Britain (in 1808) and France (in 1815) had outlawed it.

These figures do not take account of deaths during the acquisition of slaves as no one has been able to accurately estimate this.

As far as mortality rates by flag carrier are concerned, **neither set of statistics I’ve found support the idea that rates were significantly higher on French ships.** For the period 1501 to 1870, [calculations from one source](http://www.slavevoyages.org/assessment/estimates) gives rates of

- **16.2% for Britain**
- **15.7% for France**
- **17.3% for the USA**

The other source (Transoceanic Mortality) gives

- **12.5% for Britain**
- **13.3% for France**
- **16.9% for carriers which were mostly American and Scandinavian ships** (separate figures are not given)

It is true that the British passed legislation which limited the number of slaves a ship could carry but this was not until 1788 ([The Dolben Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slave_Trade_Act_1788)), by which time British ships had already transported more than 2.5 million of the estimated final total of 3.26 million slaves.

These rates seem very much at variance with the proportions quoted in the question. Either the museum presented ships with higher than average mortality rates, and / or they included deaths for a certain period either before and / or after embarkation and disembarkation. I think the most likely reason for the apparent discrepancy is that the museum focused on earlier ships when mortality rates were much higher. **The vast majority of slaves were shipped during the period 1700 to 1850, by which time death rates had been as much as halved compared to the pre-1700 period (for both slaves and crew)**.

If we look at mortality rates for earlier periods of French slave trading, we can find numbers which approach a 25% mortality rate. According to :

> French slavers left Africa with similar numbers of slaves onboard
> before 1716 as they did after that year (326 on average, compared with
> 328 after 1715), but the earlier group experienced almost double the number of shipboard deaths than did their later counterparts.Almost one-quarter of
> those embarked before 1716 died before reaching the Americas, compared
> with one in eight of those carried off between 1716 and 1792.

*Source: James Pritchard, David Eltis, and David Richardson, '[The Significance of the French Slave Trade to the Evolution of the French Atlantic World before 1716](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/289036178_The_Significance_of_the_French_Slave_Trade_to_the_Evolution_of_the_French_Atlantic_World_before_1716)' (2008)*

The authors further state that

> This discrepancy
> partly reflects declining shipboard mortality over time, but the declining overall trend in mortality was not so large that it can explain all of the differential,and it seems that the latter may also have been due to the lack of experience of French crews at this time compared with Portuguese or English slave traders. Such a rate is similar to that found on Portuguese and Dutch vessels in the second quarter of the seventeenth century.

Higher death rates were also evident on early British slave ships e.g. 1601-1650 mortality rate was 22%, 1651 to 1700 it was almost 24% (see Voyages Database). Declining mortality rates were not just applicable to slaves but also to the crews that manned these (and other) ships.

What cannot be disputed is that the treatment of slaves after arrival was far worse for those working on sugar plantations in the French and British colonies than those who were in the US. Mortality rates were indeed significantly higher for the former.

---

**Other sources:**

Philip D. Curtin, '[The Atlantic Slave Trade: a Census](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/The_Atlantic_Slave_Trade.html?id=4uEWu0GwwhkC&redir_esc=y)’

Jones, A. and Johnson, M., '[Slaves from the Windward Coast](https://www.jstor.org/stable/181481)', Journal of African History. 21,1 (1980), pp.17-34.

Roberts, R., 'Warriors. Merchants and Slaves' (Stanford University
Press, Stanford, 1987).

Will Hardy, '[The Rise and Fall of the Slave Trade](https://www.open.edu/openlearn/history-the-arts/history/the-rise-and-fall-the-slave-trade)'

Patrick Manning, cited in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic_slave_trade#Atlantic_shipment

[Slavery: The Middle Passage](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/specials/1624_story_of_africa/page53.shtml)

[Description of a slave ship, about 1788](http://www.understandingslavery.com/index.php-option=com_content&view=article&id=448_description-of-slave-ship&catid=145&Itemid=255.html) (Understanding Slavery Initiative)

David Eltis and David Richardson, '[Extending The Frontiers: Essays on the New Transatlantic Slave Trade Database](https://yale.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.12987/yale/9780300134360.001.0001/upso-9780300134360-chapter-7)' (2008)

Comment: When quoting so many facts in the body of your answer, it would be better for those of us trying to follow along if you could indicate *which* facts came from which *sources*.  The voyages source has the ability to generate links directly, such as [this](http://www.slavevoyages.org/estimates/hOYKkFTn) so perhaps you could include a link to the specific table configuration you were using.  Otherwise I agree, the numbers shown do not seem to support the argument in the question.

Comment: The worst offenders in the mortality after shipping were the Spanish and Portuguese - who used Africans to work the gold and silver mines in central and south America. The vast majority of Africans taken as slaves went there, and most were dead within a year. This is an act of genocide that remains unrecognized today.

Comment: @tj1000 : looks like you have a topic for a new question.

Comment: Who, in 1900, was still trading slaves?

Comment: The time periods were for 50 years (i.e. last one was 1850-1900) but trading actually stopped around 1870. I've edited the text to show this. Thanks for pointing this out.